# Problem with relationship Model Comments in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, model, relation

**i have two model**

Admin Model -> i use to save Admins inside it and i make Guard admin and his own routes in admin.php

User Model (Default in laravel)-> i use to save Normal users inside it and  and his own routes in web.php

Comments Model :

```
$table->id();
$table->string('comment');
$table->boolean('approved')->default(0);
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');
$table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
```

when Normal user add comment on post it save it in user_id From Users Model
the problem is : i want make admin too when add comment or reply save his id ?
i want know if should i make like this On Comment Model Or what solution:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('admin_id');
$table->foreign('admin_id')->references('id')->on('admins')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Thank you for your help brother.

Comment: adding a separate column is not necessary you may have a role in your user table that describe the user type whether it is a user or admin so you can compare the id of who commented with the id which is in the user table and get the type

Answer (score 0):

try this,

First create a table:-

```
php artisan make:migration create_comments_table
```

```
$table->id();
$table->string('comment')->nullable();
$table->boolean('approved')->default(0);
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
$table->unsignedBigInteger('admin_id')->nullable();
$table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id')->nullable();

$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->foreign('admin_id')->references('id')->on('admins')->onDelete('cascade');
```

then after the reply_id field add in the comments table:-

```
php artisan make:migration add_reply_id --table=comments // table name
```

```
$table->id();
$table->unsignedBigInteger('reply_id')->nullable();

$table->foreign('reply_id')->references('id')->on('comments')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
```

Comment Model:-

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'comments';
    protected $guarded = [];
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->BelongsTo('App\Models\Post','post_id');
    }
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->BelongsTo('App\User','user_id');
    }
    public function admin()
    {
        return $this->BelongsTo('App\Admin','admin_id');
    }
     public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comment','reply_id');
    }
    public function reply()
    {
        return $this->BelongsTo('App\Models\Comment','reply_id');
    }
}
```

Datastore like this in database:-

[image: database]

Comment: thank you brother i will try it 
one question more bro 
is this the good way to make like that , or there other way u can advice me i can do it

Comment: Yes, It is a good way because you can easy data get. for example you can find post main comment you can easily get   Post::where('id',1)->with(['reply' => function($q) { 
$q->where('reply_id',null);
}])->get();